# Where can I find Application ID for website in IIS 6?

Tags: iis, iis-6

Where can I find Application ID for website in IIS 6?

Answer (score 11):

Open IIS manager, click on the top level websites folder, view the lists of sites in the right hand pane, listing the App ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can open up a command prompt (Start --> Run --> 'cmd') and type in:  **iisapp**

That will give you a list of sites currently running, the PID of the process and the App ID you need.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can open run a command window then type `isapp.vbs`. It will list all websites with id.